# Add extension item (entity) with wizard

Tags: typo3, fluid, extbase, typo3-6.2.x

Is it possible to add a entity from a self created extbase extension with the wizard in the TYPO3 page view? I know how to a add the plugin itself, but I want to drag new elements from my extension.

I'm using the Gridelements extension.

Example:
I have a slider plugin. The plugin is automatically including on every page. The user only have to drag a new Slide Element.

Thanks for help.

[image: Drag Slide Item]

Comment: Okay after hours of googling, I think it's not possible, because the page view only allows items created in tt_content table and my slide item will be created in extensiontable

Comment: Please create an answer by yourself for this.